# Is it possible to consume events in android live wallpaper onTouchEvent()?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, touch-event

My live wallpaper is responding to touch events through the `onTouchEvent()`
method, which works fine. The problem is: the home app also appears to be receiving these touch events, so if I swipe left in my wallpaper, the home screen also slides left.

It'd be nice if it were possible for my wallpaper to selectively consume these events, but seeing as the wallpaper `onTouchEvent()` has no return type, it's looking impossible.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, just call this on the "onCreate" method of the "Engine" class:

```
setTouchEventsEnabled(true);
```